# Cosmos DB - BulkExecutor InitializeAsync awaiting forever for the response

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert

I am working on a Console Application to load multiple docs into Cosmos from CSV File through C# code. When I am debugging the code, the debugger stops at await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync(); and waiting for the response forever.

Even when I am running the executables locally, I am facing the same issue.

But when I am creating the web job with the same code and deploy to Azure Portal, there it works seamlessly. For the same web job, i am again facing the same issue in local machine during debugging mode.

ConnectinMode - I have tried both Direct and Gateway but still no luck.

NOTE :

Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor  version 1.8.8
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB             version 2.10.3

All NuGET Packages are uptodate

```
         var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(config.CosmosDbendpointUrl), config.CosmosDbAuthorizationKey,
         new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp });

        DocumentCollection dataCollection = null;
        dataCollection = Utils.GetCollectionIfExists(client, config.CosmosDatabase, config.CosmosDBCollection);
        if (dataCollection == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("The data collection does not exist");
        }

        // Set retry options high for initialization (default values).
        client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30;
        client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 9;

        IBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(client, dataCollection);
        await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

BulkExecutor has been deprecated and is no longer supported. If you are working on a new app and want bulk features use the .NET SDK v3 and set the AllowBulk = true in the client options.

You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/BulkSupport).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is there any examples that show how to bulk delete / update?

Comment: Is there, performance-wise, a disadvantage in using simple replace vs. the deprecated bulk update with the possibility of specifing the exact properties to update?